# How do you query from Parse between two different activities in Android?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

so I store some basic data using parse in one activity, but how do I retrieve that data from parse(query it) in another activity? Can someone give me a clean cut example?

So in my main activity I have

```
 public String max = "max";
 Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
 private ParseObject rightCardsStore = new ParseObject("RightCardsStore");
 rightCardsStore.put("max",max);
 rightCardsStore.saveInBackground();
```

Now, in another activity, "Folder.java" I want to query/retrieve that data and use that string.

Comment: wait so in the intent, i need to put two arguments, the first is the ID of the object, what would i put in the second one?

 Intent iii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),older.class);
iii.putExtra("RightCardsStore", ...);

Comment: I still don't understand how to requery it  in the new class, can someone provide a solid example?

Answer (score 1):

As hitch.united said, you need to get the ID by doing a saveInBackground and send it to the other activity:

```
rightCardsStore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
         if (e == null) { 
             Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, YourNewActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("parseObjectId", rightCardsStore.getObjectId());
             YourCurrentActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
         }       
    }
});
```

Then you can retrieve the data in your other activity, and query parse:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    String id = bundle.getString("parseObjectId");

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("RightCardsStore");
     query.getInBackground(id, new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
         public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
              if (e == null) { 
                 // object is the RightCardsStore you just saved
                 String max = object.getString("max");
              }
         }    
     }
}
```

If you just need to use `max` as a readonly value you can simplify the process by replacing (in the first activity)

```
intent.putExtra("parseObjectId", rightCardsStore.getObjectId());
```

by

```
intent.putExtra("max", max);
```

and replacing the second activity by:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    String max = bundle.getString("max");
}
```

Comment: okay so, String id should be equal to "max" in the new activity correct?

Comment: No it will be the id of the parse object. I updated my answer in case you just want to pass a read-only data to the second activity.

Comment: hmm okay, I haven't had a chance to test it, but id should equal the string value "max" right? not the id?

Comment: In the first example, `id` comes from `parseObjectId `, which comes from `rightCardsStore.getObjectId()`. So it does contain the id of the object and not "max". The second example shows how to get "max" directly.

Comment: Okay i see, so I wanted to take "max" and store it in a parse database, then in another activity I want to retrieve "max" the actual string and use it for readable value, I want all my activities and classes to pull "max" from a database instead of using intents everywhere, so would the first example still work?

Comment: You will still need to use intents to keep track of the id, because you will need it to query the object in an other activity.

Comment: Okay got it, im going to go test it out now. And come back to this post, thanks bud!

Answer (score 0):

After the saveInBackground get the ID of the object and pass it with an intent to the new activity. You can then requery with that ID to retrieve the object.

Comment: Ahh i see, but do you mind showing what that would look like in the other activity. Thanks.

Comment: wait so in the intent, i need to put two arguments, the first is the ID of the object, what would i put in the second one?

 Intent iii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),older.class);
iii.putExtra("RightCardsStore", ...);

Comment: You only need the new Objects ID sent with the Intent. Once you retrieve that String in the other activity you can query for the object again. Ill modify my answer.
Actually, @Melvin did a pretty good job of writing the code. Check out his answer.